# Error:(280, 61) error: cannot access zza class file for com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.zza not found

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-api-levels

In my `build.gradle` I was using this:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    ....
    ....
    defaultConfig {
        ....
        targetSdkVersion 23
    }
}
....
....
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0'
    ....
    ....
}
```

Everything was compiling correctly for me and I was in the process of publishing my app to the Google Play Store and to my surprise, Google did not let me publish it because I was using `targetSdkVersion 23` and they wanted for me to use `targetSdkVersion 26` minimum. I went ahead and changed my code to use `targetSdkVersion 26` and the error I saw said that `targetSdkVersion 26` required at least `com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.1` or higher. I changed the code to this:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    ....
    ....
    defaultConfig {
        ....
        targetSdkVersion 26
    }
}
....
....
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.1'
    ....
    ....
}
```

The error message this time was:

```
Error:(280, 61) error: cannot access zza class file for com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.zza not found
```

[image]

Any ideas to fix what Android is complaining about this time?

UPDATE 1: I had removed the `buildToolsVersion` but I included the one for API Level 26:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    ....
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to upgrade firebase-messaging to latest version

I upgraded it to 
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.6.0'

And it worked perfectly well.

Note: always use latest versions.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I am already using the latest versions now in 2019.

Answer (score 0):

I had to upgrade to

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.1'
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.1"
```

instead of my previous values of

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.8.0'
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.0"
```